# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, servlets

Everything was working just fine but now I can no longer run my application. For some reason javax.* is not being found yet in Eclipse the imports are fine...

```
exception 

javax.servlet.ServletException: Error allocating a servlet instance
 org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
 org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
 org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:857)
 org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
 org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
 java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)


root cause 

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet
 java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
 java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:632)
 java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:616)
 java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
 java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
 java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
 java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
 java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
 java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
 sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
 java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1560)
 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1491)
 org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
 org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
 org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:857)
 org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
 org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
 java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)


root cause 

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet
 java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
 java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
 java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
 sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
 java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
 java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
 java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:632)
 java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:616)
 java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
 java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
 java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
 java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
 java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
 java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
 sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
 java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1560)
 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1491)
 org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
 org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
 org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:857)
 org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
 org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
 java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Comment: You're launching from Eclipse?  If so, check the run configuration's classpath tab.

Answer (score 1):

You normally have servlet-api.jar in Apache Tomcat "Server Runtime" library.

When you define Server Runtime in Elcipse, this library is defined and will include link to servet-api.jar in Tomcat.

When you create dynamic web project it should have this library defined in Java Build Path. Check if your project has this build path.

Answer (score 0):

Add the `servlet-api.jar` to the project classpath. Servlet containers have this jar bundled, so no need to add it to `lib`.

Answer (score -2):

just copy the servlet-api jar, and paste into your webapps lib directory. and then select your project in eclipse -> mouse right click -> properties -> java build path -> select tab "order and export" -> select All -> finish.

now just runt your application using eclipse.
i hope it will works fine.
still problem is there, then tell me, i will tell you another solution

Comment: This works, but this is an utterly wrong way. Your webapp will break whenever you deploy it on servletcontainers of other make/version than the one where the libs which you dropped in webapps lib folder originated. You should rather set the *Target Runtime* in project's properties then Eclipse will take care about it automagically. And it does that NOT by copying servletcontainer-specific libraries in webapps lib.

Comment: ya what ever you told it is right. but suppose if you are trying to execute your project in another server in another mechine. at that time also you have to move your jars to that mechine. if you put your lib in your project directory. then when ever you change in another mechine, your jars also move to another mechine. then you can configure using eclipse, or you can set class path, then it will works easly. if you set target runtime it will work for that mechine is good, but if you change to another mechine it may become problem

Comment: problem means you have to move complete eclipse project. suppose if your target mechine may not contain ecipse. i have a dought if my assumtion is wrong, then why the web project structure design for lib folder in WEB-INF??? (to make a solution, there are many ways, we can use our own way. but never think that something is goood, and some thing is wrong. everything have its own good and bad issues)